# How to properly add the reference dll in ASP.Net MVC 5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, txtextcontrol

I really need some help here. So, I wanted to use a third party dll [TXTEXTCONTROL](http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/), so I installed it via NuGet and then added the reference to my project like below:

[image].

Also, I needed one **licx** file so I added that file in the solution root folder.

[image]

Now after doing this as I am developing in my local system, functionality started working now.

But when I go to the "Version Control Software" to push the code I see **JUST below changes**:

[image]

P.S:

1. This is the **only file** that's there in the changed list by version control. And the **Licx File**. total 2 files.
2. The **Hint Path** is pointing to the **local disk** where the third party tool got installed.
3. This is **csProj** file.

Problem: The functionality is not working when I published the code to live server.

I am a beginner and don't know all these play together can someone please guide me. I am willing to provide all the information.

My thinking:

1. Do, I need something else, to make this [TZTEXTCONTROL](http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/products/html5/overview/) to work on Server. Do, I need to take some additional actions.
2. Why csproj is pointing to my local system. Is that the issue?
3. Any other issue?
4. Do I need to push someother file to the server?

Solution I tried:
I copy pasted all 3 dll's and the licx file from by local system to server's bin folder. But it is still not working. Please guide me.

Comment: Best bet is to contact the control vendor. Tell them this type of DRM hurts.

Comment: @mxmissile: Sir, I am a beginner. from a cursory look do things looks okey to you? Do, I need to cross check something. Kindly note that, in server's bin folder I did not find these dll's so I copy pasted them. And I pasted licx files too. Am I missing something from my end?

Comment: If you right click on the reference and go to properties, you'll see the option `Copy Local` set it to true for any references that need to be included and aren't.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane: there is no property option in the right click of "References" :(\

Comment: There is if you pick a specific reference and right click it.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane: Sir, I did it for all three dll's. I will publish again to live now. Sir, how about my LICX file. Is there any other things you want me to look into.

Comment: is there anything I should cross check?

Comment: @BarryO'Kane: In my local system, I see installed folder for all three dll's. I mean I see the the folders and all under `programfiles`. So If I add dll's, then all those folders are not needed on server? just saying.

Comment: You'll also need to set the `Copy To Output Directory` value for the `.licx` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154704/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-barry-okane).